# SDL2 Randomly stopped working and I can't figure out why

Tags: c, sdl-2

I am writing a simple C program for a snake game, and I am using the SDL2 library to do so.

I had previously written code where it displayed a black window with a white square (the snake) and a red square (the food). I could compile and run it just fine, everything worked as intended.

I wanted to add a score system with text so I went to download the SDL_ttf add on, however, I don't know if this breaks something, but after downloading it, when I tried running the previously compiled program, it stopped working. Meaning, it no longer opened a window when run, but still showed as running. I didn't link or include the SDL_ttf into my program.

When I downloaded SDL, I downloaded it from the GitHub release, and used the following procedures to install it:

In the SDL directory:

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
sudo make install
```

This worked for me. But when I went to download SDL_ttf, I downloaded via `sudo apt install libsdl2-ttf-dev`. This is when I tried rerunning the program, and it failed to run properly.

I uninstalled the libsdl2-ttf-dev, and installed it in the same way I did with the SDL2 library, however that didn't fix the issue.

I then removed all the files related SDL from my system and reinstalled and nothing changed. I tried restarting my computer as well.

I added a print statement to the top of the main function before anything else was called, and the text was never printed to my terminal.

I am using this to compile my program: `gcc -g main.c -o snake -lSDL2`. I added -lSDL_ttf when I had included it in my program, but it still doesn't run when it's not include/linked.

The program compiles with no warnings and no errors, so I don't know what to do. Additionally, I am using Linux Mint.

EDIT: Found libsdl2-2.0.0 and libsdl2-dev on system and had to remove them, also did `sudo make uninstall` on the source compiled ones before installing via `sudo apt install libsdl2-dev`.

Here is the main code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1080
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 720

#define SNAKE_SIZE 50
#define FOOD_SIZE 10
#define SPEED 5

SDL_Rect spawnFood() {
    int randY = (rand() % (SCREEN_HEIGHT - FOOD_SIZE + 1));
    int randX = (rand() % (SCREEN_WIDTH - FOOD_SIZE + 1));

    SDL_Rect food = {randX, randY, FOOD_SIZE, FOOD_SIZE};
    return food;
}

void moveSnake(int dir, SDL_Rect* snake, SDL_Rect* food) {
    if (dir == 0 && snake->y > 0) snake->y -= SPEED;
    else if (dir == 1 && snake->y < SCREEN_HEIGHT - SNAKE_SIZE) snake->y += SPEED;
    else if (dir == 2 && snake->x > 0) snake->x -= SPEED;
    else if (dir == 3 && snake->x < SCREEN_WIDTH - SNAKE_SIZE) snake->x += SPEED;

    SDL_bool eat = SDL_HasIntersection(snake, food);

    if (eat) {
        *food = spawnFood();
        // Add score
        // Add snake length
    }
}

int handleKeyPresses(int key, int lastDir, SDL_Rect snake, SDL_Rect food) {
    /**
        UP      = 1073741906, 119
        DOWN    = 1073741905, 115
        LEFT    = 1073741904, 97
        RIGHT   = 1073741904, 100
    */
    int dir = -1;
    switch (key) {
        case 1073741906:
        case 119:
            dir = 0;
            break;
        case 1073741905:
        case 115:
            dir = 1;
            break;
        case 1073741904: 
        case 97:
            dir = 2;
            break;
        case 1073741903:
        case 100:
            dir = 3;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (dir == -1) return lastDir;
    if (lastDir == 0 && (dir == 0 || dir == 1)) return lastDir;
    if (lastDir == 1 && (dir == 1 || dir == 0)) return lastDir;
    if (lastDir == 2 && (dir == 2 || dir == 3)) return lastDir;
    if (lastDir == 3 && (dir == 3 || dir == 2)) return lastDir;

    moveSnake(dir, &snake, &food);

    return dir;
}

struct SDL_Vars {
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
};

struct SDL_Vars init() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        printf("Could not init sdl: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Snake",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );

    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open %d x %d window: %s\n", SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
        window, -1, 
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED |
        SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC    
    );

    if (renderer == NULL) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        printf("Failed to create renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }
    
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    struct SDL_Vars vars = { window, renderer };
    return vars;
}

void drawItem(SDL_Renderer *renderer, SDL_Rect item, int r, int g, int b, int a) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, a);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &item);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct SDL_Vars vars = init();
    
    SDL_Event input;
    int quit = 0;
    int lastDir = 0;

    SDL_Rect snake = { 100, 100, SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_SIZE };
    SDL_Rect food = spawnFood();

    while (!quit) {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(vars.renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(vars.renderer);

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&input)) {
            switch (input.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    quit = 1;
                    break;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    lastDir = handleKeyPresses(input.key.keysym.sym, lastDir, snake, food);
                    break;
                default: {}
            }
        }

        moveSnake(lastDir, &snake, &food);

        // Draw Food
        drawItem(vars.renderer, food, 255, 0, 0, 255);

        // Draw Snake
        drawItem(vars.renderer, snake, 255, 255, 255, 255);

        SDL_RenderPresent(vars.renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(vars.renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(vars.window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sudo apt install libsdl2-ttf-dev` would install `libsdl2-dev`, too. That would create a conflict with the version you built. Are you sure you removed everything? Also, you need to explain what you mean by it "stopped working".

Comment: @D.Go: Meanwhile, OP has edited the question to add that piece of information.

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"I added a print statement to the top of the main function before anything else was called, and the text was never printed to my terminal."` -- Did you print it to `stdout` or `stderr`? If you printed it to `stdout`, did you make sure that `stdout` gets flushed afterwards (for example by calling `fflush(stdout);` immediately after the `printf` statement)?

Comment: If you are asked detail questions about code you describe but do not show you should show the code as or in a [mre].

Comment: I strongly suspect @D.Go hit the nail on the head. If you are using part of SDL that is provided by your LInux distribution installed though its package manager and also did `../configure; make; sudo make install` you now have multiple versions of the libraries required by SDL and SDL itself on your system. This makes it (almost) impossible to load one set of libraries without specifying every search and include path and library search path explicitly. Best course, start over, remove what you installed, "refresh" (or remove and reinstall) all SDL packages provided by your distro.

Comment: And also add the output of `ldd yourprogram` where "`yourprrogram`" is the executable you compiled for your snake game.

Comment: Also, what does your debugger show?

Comment: I did as @D.Go said and I looked at my packages, and I just didn't remove a couple. Thank you for all the quick responses, though.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the parameters matter.

g++ -I/usr/include/SDL2 -g main.cpp -o snake -lSDL2

> https://askubuntu.com/a/69213

make sure to give the compiler your include directory, where ever that may be if you install by source. I installed libsdl2-dev and libsdl2-2.0-0 from apt. I recommend running:

```
sudo apt purge libsdl*
sudo apt install libsdl2-dev libsdl2-2.0-0
```

maybe the make script you ran threw some sdl libs somewhere apt cant find to uninstall? Look through it for directories.

[image]